# Software for resuming a session after restart

Tags: reboot, session-restore

I absolutely hate hate HATE restarting my (Windows 8) laptop. The reason for this is because I generally have an awful lot going on at any time, thanks to working on 4 or 5 concurrent projects as well as a few other tasks. On a usual day, I have:

- VLC, playing whatever
- NetBeans
- Node.JS, running a few utility programs
- Notepad++, sometimes with unsaved files*
- Notepad, running 3 or 4 instances of unsaved text files*
- Word with a few documents, some unsaved files*
- Chrome, running 30-40 tabs
- Explorer, 7-8 Windows Open

* these files are not files that need to be saved to disk, but untitled documents that I am using for storing complex sets of notes and ideas about whatever I am working on, but only required for a short period of time, so not saved

Yes, that is a lot of open programs, but my laptop can easily handle it all. In the past, I have gone as much as 2 months without restarting my computer because I can't face going through all my stuff, saving the temporary stuff, then after the restart, re-loading it all to the states I was at before restarting.

So, are there any programs that can handle the restart process for me by closing and saving the open programs to a temporary space, restart the system, and reload all/most of the previous session programs and data from the temporary directory (deleting the temp data after loading)?

Comment: Your first problem is you have unsaved doucments.  You could save the state on some of those programs through extensions ( i.e. Chrome ) the rest don't really support doing so.

Comment: @Ramhound yup, thats the problem i'm getting at

Comment: There is no single solution that woud support all those programs.

Comment: Well, I am guessing that each program will need some sort of connector to handle it, but theoretically, couldn't it be done by taking an image of the memory that program is using, then after reloading it, moving that memory image into the same memory space that the new instance of the program is using?

Comment: Your talking about hibernate.  The problem is that in order for Windows to actually update it must unload its own resources, which often is required by those programs, so you really have no other choice.  Please note this isn't unique to Windows, EVERY OPERATIGN SYSTEM, requires you to restart the operating system to load updates to system files.

Comment: Yup, I know that. All I am talking about is reloading the operating system, then performing a hibernate-like function on all the programs EXCEPT for the operating system files. So the operating system has been restarted, and the software is in the same state as it was before. The software didn't need restarting, but the operating system did, and unless the software has hard ties to the operating system state, nothing would have changed in the software environment

Comment: Restarting the base system and hibernating the apps is not possible because all handles/pointers to files, registry, network which are saved in the apps change when you reboot the core system. The apps have to support storing the current state and restoring it later, there is AFAIK no other way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to hibernate windows applications separately?](http://superuser.com/questions/215363/is-there-a-way-to-hibernate-windows-applications-separately), [Can I "hibernate" a program?](http://superuser.com/questions/275010) etc.

Comment: Sublime Text won't forget unsaved files on exit, so it solves it for Notepad/Notepad++.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of a reboot is to 'restart' and reload everything on your computer.

I would add those programs to the start-up programs list. You can see the list of startup programs by typing msconfig in the run dialog.

If you wish to add these programs to the startup list, you can add them in this folder:

For ALL Users copy to :
"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"

Comment: You might be able to save some of these docs and .txts to the start up folder and just have them reopen when you restart. And then when you start up they will be open for edit. That means a simple Ctrl + S would save them.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [HORM (Hibernate Once Resume Many)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2004/12/01/273462.aspx).  It was a feature that was added to Windows XP Embedded SP2 back in 2004...

The idea is basically that you get your machine to a state that works well for you, and hibernate.  Then, you always boot/resume the machine to that hibernate file.  The downside is that you don't resume to unsaved files.  The upside is that you boot faster to all the programs up and ready that you use.

I'm not ignoring your desire to separate the programs from the OS, but considering that a few of those programs don't, in any way, run independent of the OS, you can't separate them from the OS to restart *just* the OS.  In truth, it's really just a matter of changing the way you think so that you *do* start saving even those little temporary files of notes that you say don't need to be saved.

If you set it up properly... meaning standardize some names for those little temporary files, have the programs up and running with those templates up and open, and make your hiberfil.sys from that... you'd be close to where you want to be.